# perfom button click from return key in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am a newbie in iOS programming, So i have 2 textFields and 1 button, I want the return key in textfield1 is next key and in the textfield2 is done key, when I press this button(the next key), the cursor will in textfield2, and when i press the done key in textfield2 it will performs the button. I cant handling the events, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider you linked your textfields to your .h, creating 2 `IBOutlet`s, and an outlet and an action for your button:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *firstField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *secondField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
- (IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender;
```

In your .m file, in the `viewDidLoad`, add this:

```
_firstFieldField.delegate = self;
_secondField.delegate = self;
```

Back in your .h file, conform your class to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Then, in your .m, you can implement the following method, which will be called when you press the "done" button on the keyboard:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (textField == _usernameField) {

        _firstField becomeFirstResponder];
    }

    else if (textField == _passwordField) {

        [_secondField resignFirstResponder];
        [self buttonPress:_button];
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: The name of the method has to match the name you have chosen for the action on the button click.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a `UITextFieldDelegate` method for this, and set the delegates of the text fields to `self` (`self` being your `UIViewCiontroller`):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    if (textField == self.textField1) {
        [self.textField2 becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
        [self buttonTapped:self.button];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

As for what to see on your key, you can set it as the "Return Key" in the interface builder

Comment: [self buttonTapped:self.loginButton], can you tell details about this line, it doent work.

Comment: Just call your button's action from here

Answer (score 0):

Two textfields with Tags - **1** & **2**

One IBAction method for textfields.

Bind method from your view's textfields. -> **Did End On Exit** Event

```
- (IBAction)returnAction:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender tag] == 1) {
       [textField2 becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
       //YOUR_ACTION to perform;
    }
}
```

You can also perform with Delegate method

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    if (textField == self.textField1) {
        [self.textField2 becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
      [button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return YES;
}
```